# Table forced to display: block; for responsive design doesn't fill screen

Tags: html, css

I am making Google's advanced search page for an assignment. Here is the html:

```
<table class="a_table">
    <tr class="a_row">
        <td class="a_c1" id="find_header">Find pages with...</td>
        <td class="a_c2"></td>
        <td class="a_c3" id="todo_header">To do this in the search box:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a_row">
        <td class="a_c1">all these words:</td>
        <td class="a_c2"><input class="a_field" type="text" name="as_q"></td>
        <td class="a_c3">Type the important words: <span class="a_example">tri-colour rat terrier</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a_row">
        <td class="a_c1">this exact word or phrase:</td>
        <td class="a_c2"><input class="a_field" type="text" name="as_epq"></td>
        <td class="a_c3">Put exact words in quotes: <span class="a_example">"rat terrier"</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a_row">
        <td class="a_c1">any of these words:</td>
        <td class="a_c2"><input class="a_field" type="text" name="as_oq"></td>
        <td class="a_c3">Type OR between all the words you want: <span class="a_example">miniature OR standard</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a_row">
        <td class="a_c1">none of these words:</td>
        <td class="a_c2"><input class="a_field" type="text" name="as_eq"></td>
        <td class="a_c3">Put a minus sign just before words that you don't want:<br><span class="a_example">-rodent, -"Jack Russell"</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a_b" style="text-align: right;">
        <td class="a_b"></td>
        <td class="a_b" style="padding-right: 17px; height: 60px;"><input class="a_btn" type="submit" value="Advanced Search"></td>
        <td class="a_b"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS to make it responsive:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
.a_c3
{
    display: none;
}
.a_table, .a_row, .a_field, .a_c1, .a_c2, .a_b {
    display: block;
}

.a_row {
    width: 100%;
}

.a_c1, .a_c2, .a_b {
    width: 100%;
}

.a_table {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that while .a_table fills the whole width of the screen, for some reason, the .a_row is only as wide as the content inside (and therefore all the td). I've been at this for a while with no ideas.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.a_table>* { display:block }` to your CSS.

What you are missing is that the parser automatically creates a `tbody` element around the table rows. This causes the CSS to generate an anonymous table object around the tbody element which takes the default table width behaviour of shrink-to-fit its contents.

`.a_table>* { display:block }` or `.a_table>* { display:contents }` or simply `tbody { display:block }`will stop the anonymous table objects from being generated.

Answer (score 0):

put table in div with class "table-responsive"